# How to make the wishlist icon remain clicked even after redirecting to other page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is an ecommerce website and I have created a wishlist icon for adding products to the wishlist. The wishlist is working just fine, when I click on the icon the product is being added to the wishlist page and when clicked again the product gets removed from the same. **But there is one problem that when I add the product in the wishlist and then refresh or go to some other page the icon automatically turns back from "Favorite" to "FavoriteBorderOutlined" but the product remains in the wishlist. I want that the icon remains the same until clicked again.
Can someone help me with this?**

```
import {
  Favorite,
  SearchOutlined,
  FavoriteBorderOutlined,
} from "@material-ui/icons";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { popularProducts } from "../data";
import "./product.css";
import { publicRequest } from "../requestMethods";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { wishProduct, removeFromWishlist } from "../redux/wishlistRedux";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {RiHeart3Fill} from 'react-icons/ri';

const Info = styled.div`
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const Container1 = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 280px;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  background-color: #f5fbfd;
  justify-content: center;
  
  position: relative;

  &:hover ${Info}{
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;

const Container2 = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
`

const Circle = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
`;

const Image = styled.img`
  height: 75%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
`;

const Icon = styled.div`
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #e9f5f5;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
`;

const SubIcon = styled.div``;

const Title = styled.div`
  height: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:black;
  align-items: left;
  width: 280px;
`;

const Span = styled.div`
  color: black;
  align-items: left;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 5px;
`;

const Stock = styled.div`
  color: black;
  align-items: right;
`;

const Product = ({ item }) =>
{
  const location = useLocation();
  // const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  // const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  // const [size, setSize] = useState("");
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [isFilled, setIsFilled] = useState(false);
  const toggleFilledIcon = () => setIsFilled(!isFilled);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/" + item.id);
        setProduct(res.data);
      } catch {}
    };
    getProduct();
  }, [item.id]);

  let inStock = "In Stock";
  let outofStock = "Out of Stock";
  let stockDetail;
  if (item.inStock) {
    stockDetail = inStock;
  }
  else {
    stockDetail = outofStock;
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    //console.log(product, item.id)
    if(isFilled){
      dispatch(removeFromWishlist(product));
    }
    else{
      dispatch(wishProduct({ ...product, quantity }));
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Container1>
        <Circle />
        <Image src={item.img} />
        <Info>
          <Icon>
            <Link to={`/product/${item.id}`}>
              <SearchOutlined />  
            </Link>
          </Icon>
          <Icon onClick={(event)=>{
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
              toggleFilledIcon();
              handleClick();
            }}>
            { isFilled ? <Favorite style={{ color: 'crimson' }} /> : <FavoriteBorderOutlined /> }
          </Icon>
        </Info>
      </Container1>
      <Container2>
        <Title>{item.title}</Title>
        <Span className="price">₹{item.price}</Span>
        <Span className="stock">{stockDetail}</Span>
      </Container2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we are missing some code to perfectly understand the issue.

My guess is the following, your `isFilled` state variable is local, and so when the `<Product/>` component unmounts and is mounted back up its state is reset to the default value. I made a small codesandbox to try to expose this to you: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-6f943o?file=/index.js

A solution could be to export your product `isFilled` state variable to redux so it can escape the local scope.

Please comment on this so I can edit this answer if it does not address your issue.